# I think I lost everything after boot camp

Tags: mac, bootcamp

I tried to install Windows 10 into my *Boot Camp* partition.  I exited the setup and, normally, my computer restarts and I log into the Mac.

Now it's just a black screen flashing a folder icon with a `?` on it.  I think I've lost everything and I'm very confused and scared. Please can anyone help me?

Comment: You most likely corrupted OS X. Have you tried to reboot into Recovery HD and reinstall OS X?

Comment: Try restarting you Mac while holding down the option key. This should invoke the Startup Manager. See if there is an option to boot back to OS X.

Answer (score 1):

You have three options, they go from best to worst:

1. Reboot into your recovery partition by holding down <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, and open disk utility, and attempt to repair your drive.
2. Still in the recovery partition, restore from backup, which most people do these days.
3. Reinstall OS X, and begin taking backups so #2 will work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just a quick side note: If you are not able to reinstall OS X (happened to me), it is possible that your logic board has failed as well.

Comment: If he can't install OS X, then either he needs to google, or his computer is broken and he needs to buy a new one. His computer doesn't sound broken, so...

Comment: we can't be sure. There is no need to buy a new computer, it is a simple $150 fix. This has happened to me before, so I just shared my experience.